# Serial port programming, baud rate related issue. port sending garbage for all baud rates except B38400

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, baud-rate

I am facing issue with serial port programming in linux. The port is able to read and write to anther hyperterminal for baud 38400. but when I try other baud rates, it fails to write and reads some garbage value. can anyone help me out.

steps I follow, store configuration initially using tcgetattr for restoring in the end.
Then configure the port . read, write. In the end restore initial settings using tcsetattr.

Comment: Is the other side also set to that baud rate?

Comment: Rather hard to say anything useful without seeing your code. Try google for some example code.

Comment: Yes other side is runnig hyperterminal, baud rate is changed appropriately when baud rate is changed in program.

Comment: Tried Google first, and other places. I'm using tcsetospeed and tc setispeed now. Earlier I used to assign to c_cflag of the termios structure. But no change in result.

Comment: Prepare a loop back (short pin 2 and 3) and test other baud rates. (With this you need to change settings only at one place). One possibility can be, the setting changes are not taking effect on one end and is fixed to 38400.

Comment: Posting what was sent and the "garbage" read is useful diagnostic information.  Suggest sending "UUUUUUU" (alternating 1's and 0's) and "3333333" (lots of pairs 0's and 1's) and reporting the results.